# How to remove header fade when scrolling?

Tags: wordpress, scroll, navigation, content-management-system

on my Site www.yourpod.de the Navigation Bar turns into Black when scrolling. I just want to show the Black one which is fixed on the top. Can anybody held me?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following  code in custom.js

```
var transparent = true;

    if ($( '.navbar-color-on-scroll' ).length !== 0) {

        var navbarHome       = $( '.navbar-color-on-scroll' ),
            headerWithTopbar = 0;

        if ( navbarHome.hasClass( 'header-with-topbar' ) ) {
            headerWithTopbar = 40;
        }

        $( window ).on(
            'scroll', debounce(
                function () {
                    if ($( document ).scrollTop() > headerWithTopbar) {
                        if (transparent) {
                            transparent = false;
                            navbarHome.removeClass( 'navbar-transparent' );
                            navbarHome.addClass( 'navbar-not-transparent' );
                        }
                    } else {
                        if ( ! transparent) {
                            transparent = true;
                            navbarHome.addClass( 'navbar-transparent' );
                            navbarHome.removeClass( 'navbar-not-transparent' );
                        }
                    }
                }, 17
            )
        );
    }
```

with this line

```
$( '.navbar-color-on-scroll' ).addClass('navbar-scroll-point navbar-not-transparent');
```

Comment: Works fine - but only on Tablet and Mobile - what do i have to change for desktop?

Comment: you have to remove " navbar-transparent" class from nav from header.php and add  " navbar-scroll-point" instead